# How do i prevent the browser from making expensive DNS lookups?

Tags: ajax, dns

Almost every ajax call I make, results in an expensive DNS look up.  Are there headers I can set, that will prevent the browser from making DNS look ups.  Or perhaps some server side settings?

Answer (score 1):

How do you know that this is causing a performance problem?  Did you use Wireshark to verify?  I very much doubt that DNS lookups are to blame.

Comment: I checked firebug.  I shows that it's repeatedly making DNS calls even though its the same server.  It almost never caches the DNS.  Even if you make 30 or 40 calls per minute, it refuses to cache it.  Also, firebug shows that nearly 1/3 or 1/2 of the time is spent in the DNS look up part.

Comment: Huh.  I'd have to see it to believe it =)  Assuming it's true, you'd need a unique IP to avoid the lookup.  You could be sneaky and do an initial AJAX call (with a domain name) to *get* the IP, then use the IP on all subsequent calls =)  This dirty hack would allow your IP to change in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Using the IP Address should prevent DNS Lookup :)

Answer (score 0):

You could add the hostname/IP mapping in question to your `hosts` file (on the computer where the browser is running).

The exact location depends on the operating system. On a 32bit Windows system this is `%windir%\system32\drivers\hosts`, on Unix like systems this should be `/etc/hosts`

As far as I know, no DNS lookup will happen for entries in the `hosts` file (at least not on Windows)